# Cannot find every HTML-tag in a parsed HTML?

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

For a project I need to know how often a specific tag is in an HTML-file.
First, I parsed the HTML-file.
Then I used the `.select()` to get all the `<time>` tags.
In the developer tools from Chrome I counted that tag 25 times.
But Python counts 10.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r=requests.get(URL)
doc=r.text
soup=BeautifulSoup(doc,'html.parser')

length=len(soup.select("time"))
print(length)                   #OUTPUT is 10 instead of 25
```

I found out that doc contains `<time>` 10 times.
But shouldn't it have as many as my browser shows?
I need all 25. Is there a work around to get all 25?
What could I do?

Comment: Need a reproducible example to dig further ... but, it may not be as many as your browser if those `<time>`s are being generated by JavaScript instead of just plain static HTML

Comment: i don't know if this is the case, but you should be careful about scraping websites which have javascript rendering. 
For example, I tried to scrape a website which loaded its content using AJAX, so this meant that a simple script like yours would receive the HTML of the website BEFORE the ajax completion, and thus, did not contain "all" tags.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your response. Your comment gave me the idea that I should check the site again. There you have a dropdown menu where you can set how many results should be shown. You can select 10 , 25, 50 or 100.  I selected 10 copied the URL and changed it in the code and it gives me the result I wanted. Maybe the first 10 are static HTML and the rest are generated by javascript?

Comment: @RafaelMarques yes I think that happened to me.

Comment: Can you share the URL? Your problem can't be solved without it.

Answer (score -1):

Try the soup.find_all() method - this usually works for me

Comment: That's not the problem here. `soup.select('tag')` and `soup.find_all('tag')` return the exact same things.